# Reference Error: Can't find variable process (http 10.0.2.2:8081) - how do I stop this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-native, jsx

I'm having trouble building my react-native project. When I try to build it - I get this error: referenceerror can't find variable process http 10.0.2.2:8081.

I've tried downgrading from react-native@0.37.0 to @0.30.0 (where I started from) back to @0.33.1 to no avail.

I've tried using npm i react@15.2.1 --save
 to downgrade my react and I get these errors: npm WARN react-addons-create-fragment@15.4.0 requires a peer of react@^15.4.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-addons-shallow-compare@15.4.0 requires a peer of react@^15.4.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-native@0.33.1 requires a peer of react@~15.3.1 but none was installed.
npm ERR! code 1

I can't seem to get the correct combination of react-native@0.3?.? with react-@15.?.? to get my app up and running. Does anyone have suggestions as to why this is happening? Understanding how to solve the problem is one thing but what I don't understand is why it's happening.

// 11/30

I was able to get it working like this:

```
"dependencies": { 
  "react": "^15.3.2",
  "react-native": "^0.35.0"
},
```

Comment: This may help you https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4098

Comment: @maheshiv I looked over that page and posted a comment about this same issue there. Seems like I'm not the only one having this problem...